# errors with text inputs in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a dice roller for warhammer using kivy and python my code is this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
success=0
fails=0


class mygridlayout(GridLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(mygridlayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.cols=2
       self.add_widget(Label(text="rolls"))
       self.rolls = TextInput(multiline=False)
       self.add_widget(self.rolls)


       self.add_widget(Label(text="hit on"))
       self.hits = TextInput(multiline=False)
       self.add_widget(self.hits)





       self.submit = Button(text="submit", font_size=32)
       self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
       self.add_widget(self.submit)

   def press(self, instance):
           rolls= self.rolls.text
           hits= self.hits.text


           for i in (rolls):
               die = random.randint(1, 6)
               if die>=hits:
                   success+1
           else:
               fails+1


           print(F"{success} success's and {fails} fails")

           self.add_widget(Label(text=F'{success}'))


class myapp(App):
   def build(self):
       return mygridlayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   myapp().run()
```

and then I get this error when i try to run it

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
> it wont let me just change the text inputs to integers so i don't know what to do.

Comment: `if die>= int(hits):`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random
success=0
fails=0


class mygridlayout(GridLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(mygridlayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.cols=2
       self.add_widget(Label(text="rolls"))
       self.rolls = TextInput(multiline=False)
       self.add_widget(self.rolls)


       self.add_widget(Label(text="hit on"))
       self.hits = TextInput(multiline=False)
       self.add_widget(self.hits)





       self.submit = Button(text="submit", font_size=32)
       self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
       self.add_widget(self.submit)

   def press(self, instance):
           rolls= int(self.rolls.text)
           hits= int(self.hits.text)


           for i in range(rolls):
               die = random.randint(1, 6)
               if die>=hits:
                   success+1
           else:
               fails+1


           print(F"{success} success's and {fails} fails")

           self.add_widget(Label(text=F'{success}'))


class myapp(App):
   def build(self):
       return mygridlayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   myapp().run()
```